# How to switch focus of WebDriver from Native App to Web authorization Page

Tags: selenium, appium, ui-automation, xcuitest

Was not able to come up with right wording for title, but will explain here:

So i`m testing native iOS app and at some point user need to connect fitBit Account. So When user tap on Connect => He redirected to fitBit auth page which is webview.
While i`ve been runing tests in browserStack all elements on this webPage were interactable and i had no problems. But on simulator, Appium logs detect new app when this webPage opens up

I red about switch context, but when i tried to print out array of all context available i only had one (MyApp_NATIVE) printed out

Appium logs detect this:

```
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     "WIRTitleKey": "Fitbit",
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWeb",
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     "WIRURLKey": "https://accounts.fitbit.com/login?. ....... blablalblalbla
```

Can i use one of the values above to switch focus of my Driver ?

How to make Driver to recognize elements on this webPage.

Comment: You can use one of the values to switch since u are switching to fitbit auth page. I do not see why there should be a difference in simulator and browserStack unless different apps are installed